# Flatpak - Safely Relocate Sandboxed Home Directory

Tags: linux, software-installation, package-management, flatpak

I would like to transparently provide a Flatpak app with a fully sandboxed `~/` directory located at an arbitrary location of my choosing.

- That is, I want to sandbox the **entirety** of `~/` such that writing to arbitrary subdirectories works as expected, and map it to a location on an external disk (mounted at `/mnt/<disk-id>`) instead of `~/.var/app/<app-id>`.
- Ideally I'd like to relocate *all* of the per-user data for a particular app, but I'm trying to limit the scope of this question.
- I know that I can grant access to arbitrary locations via `--filesystem=<path>` and that I can map individual subdirectories under user `~/` to the corresponding sandbox directory via `--persist=<path>`. However, neither of these options would appear to satisfy my use case.

The Flatpak docs ([sandbox permissions](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions-reference.html) and [flatpak-override](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/flatpak-command-reference.html#flatpak-override)) seem to indicate that the sandbox [uses a tempfs](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/wiki/Sandbox) and only bind mounts specific directories into it. In particular, the `flatpak-override --persist` [docs](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/flatpak-command-reference.html#flatpak-override) seem to imply that individual subdirectories must be mapped on a case by case basis in order for data to be persisted. Contradicting this, the [sandbox overview](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/wiki/Sandbox) seems to be saying that `~/.var/app/<app-id>` is simply bind mounted to sandbox `~/`. The latter appears to be what actually happens. When I used a sandboxed app to create a directory within `~/` that had not been mapped into the sandbox, the corresponding directory was created under `~/.var/app/<app-id>` and persisted across app restarts.

Given the apparent behavior, **would it be safe to simply bind mount the desired location** to `~/.var/app/<app-id>`? I'm hesitant to blindly attempt this because I know that Flatpak is engaging in a great deal of file system shenanigans under the hood in order to create a robust sandbox. In particular, it pivot_roots the sandbox filesystem, would be bind mounting the location I had bind mounted to (do I need an `rbind` here?), could be performing further bind mounts in subdirectories (will this play well with *my* bind mount?), and is likely taking other precautions (now or in the future) which I'm worried might break any indirections done by me in strange and creative ways.